# Expresión regular, captura caracteres excepto los que están dentro de contenedores

Tags: regex

Busco encontrar la expresión `(y|o)` pero solamente para los que están afuera de los paréntesis de esta cadena:

```
(id = 54) y (nombre = "Panfilodomeo") o (fecha <> 2019)
```

Si la expresión solamente es `(y|o)` marca todos los 'y' y 'o' de la cadena claramente.

```
(id = 54) y (nombre = "Panfilodomeo") o (fecha <> 2019)
          ↑   ↑              ↑ ↑  ↑   ↑
```

¿Cómo se podría hacer para que encuentre solamente los que están afuera de los paréntesis?

Este es el resultado que espero:

```
(id = 54) y (nombre = "Panfilodomeo") o (fecha <> 2019)
          ↑                           ↑
```

Comment: ¿No te alcanza simplificando todo el tema de paréntesis, simplemente "y"/"o" como palabra completa? `\b[yo]\b` ... Por otro lado, deberías especificar en qué lenguaje o a lo sumo qué dialecto de regex. Cualquier solución un poco más compleja va a depender del lenguaje (Ej: PHP, JavaScript y .net tendrían 3 soluciones *completamente* diferentes)

Comment: @Pollo No había pensado en eso, gracias. Pero aún así, creo que eso tendría inconveniente dentro de los paréntesis donde haya texto que contenga eso (por ejemplo, que envés de "Panfilodomeo" diga "Alberto y Sebastian", aquí cambiaría ese "y"), aunque este inconveniente también podría pasar en la solución que propuse. No creí que el dialecto fuera relevante, en esta ocación estoy usando el de .net

Answer (score 0):

Investigando un poco acerca de las expresiones "lookaround" encontré que se pueden hacer expresiones con un tipo de NOT.

Mi expresión quedaría `(?!\) )(y|o)(?= \()` y ahora sí encuentra:

```
(id = 54) y (nombre = "Panfilodomeo") o (fecha <> 2019)
          ↑                           ↑
```

A como entiendo las expresiones que tienen ?! y ?= son como los que evitan que se seleccione lo que está alrededor del y|o.

No entiendo muy bien el funcionamiendo o significado, pero tengo entendido que la expresión encuentra todos los ") y (" pero por el ?! y ?=, agrupa la parte de ") " y de " (" para que solamente se seleccione "y".

Ya esta resuelto el problema para lo que necesito, pero no lo voy a marcar como solución porque siento que podría fallar y porque no sé si termino de entender mi solución.

Si alguien pudiera dar una mejor respuesta lo agradecería.